# How to create alert when prometheus data is discontinuous

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a prometheus metrics with type counter. it is called job_failure_counter: if a job fails, the application will increment the metrics by one and send it to pushgateway of prometheus, otherwise it will not send anything to  pushgateway.

As you can imagine, the graph of the metrics shown in prometheus is a discontinuous line. i.e. Only when job fails there is a short line. But most of time job does not fail so you do not see line or point.

I created an alert to detect job failure: if rate (the counter[5m]) > 0, trigger alert.

However it does not work because most of time, there is not data, so the value of rate is  empty query result. and even when there is data, there is no data in  previous minute so still we cannot get rate.

How to get alert in this case? I am thinking using this logic:

```
If current data exists:
  if date in previous minutes exists && the previous data != the current data => trigger alert
  elif date in previous minutes does not exist => trigger alert
else:
  do not trigger alert
```

This logic sound complex, I do not know how to add it to alert rule.

Question: how to create alert for job failure if data is discontinuous

Comment: First, I have some doubts: Pushgateway doesn't behave in a described manner, AFAIK. It exposes latest value of the metric, regardless how long ago it was updated. So, please, check if setup you described fully correct.

Comment: And regarding the issue at hand, it sounds like `elif` part of your pseudo code should be generally enough to trigger alert. If that is true, you can simply use expression `job_failure_counter` in your alert.

Comment: And if you want a query for full block, you might try something like `job_failure_counter unless job_failure_counter == min_over_time(job_failure_counter[2m] offset 1m)`. But you will probably need to tinker about with ranges the to account for your `scrape_interval` and `evaluation_interval`. I cannot wrap my head around what they should be in general case at the moment.

Comment: AT markalex: I changed the description about pushgateway. does it make more sense?

Comment: AT markalex: sometimes the line is relatively long (maybe job keeps failing) so if current data exists and previous data exist but less than current data, we need to alert.